# Will the wait_pop_head function return unspecified data?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

In 《c++ concurrency in action》page 167,
[image]

1）value=std::move(*head->data);  // Data will be moved if T has move-constructor.

2）std::unique_ptr old_head=std::move(head);  // now the data references to unspecified T ?

[image]

Comment: The one-parameter overload of `wait_pop_head` would indeed return a pointer to a node holding an empty, moved-from `data`. The data has been moved into its `value` parameter. Note however that the caller of this function, the one-parameter overload of `wait_and_pop`, doesn't actually use the node pointer for anything. In light of this, it's unclear why you feel that leaving that node with empty data is a problem.

Comment: A little bit worried that someone might misuse it.

Comment: It's a private member. No one outside the class can call it.

Comment: Get it. Thank you.